# Iterative method to compute $c^{1/p}$

Tags: numerical-methods

Project the locally convergent iterative method to compute: 
$$c^{1/p} , p = ..., -2,-1, 1,2,... $$
I thougt about Newton's method, but I got stuck.
Please hint me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve $$f(x)=x^p-c=0$$ or $$g(x)=cx^{-p}-1=0$$ or $$h(x)=x^{(p+1)/2}-cx^{-(p-1)/2}=0$$ using Newton's method.